# Explicit .trigger("click") is not setting checked to true jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, checkbox

In my js file, a function is triggered when "click" event happens on checkbox, and on that click it checks which values are "checked" and selects those values.
I am doing a click through code like :: `$('#id').trigger("click"); or $('#id').click()` in this case, the function that is triggered on "click" is called, but when it checks `if($('#id').checked)`, this returns false, and the "if-body" is never called.

Why is checked not set to true for that element when I am triggering a click on the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$('#id')` has no `checked` property. So `$('#id').checked` is `undefined`. You can see that even on click on the checkbox itself console `undefined`

```js
$('#id').on('click', function() {
  console.log($('#id').checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input id="id" type="checkbox" />
```

There are some ways to check if checkbox is checked.

```js
$('#id').on('click', function() {
  console.log(
    $('#id').is(':checked'),
    $('#id').get(0).checked,
    $('#id').prop('checked')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input id="id" type="checkbox" />
```

And with the button

```js
$('#id').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#id').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('checked!!')
  }
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input id="id" type="checkbox" />
<button>trigger check</button>
```